# Add a c# canvas to an MVC view?

Tags: c#, canvas, model-view-controller

Is there a way to add a canvas (or anything that can render a c# application, more specifically a game such as Tetris) to an MVC view?

I would like to make a game, add it to a view, and send the score of the client to the server to process rewards and other stuff.

I have no idea how to get started, can someone show me the way please?

I would prefer to not use JavaScript for this, I would like a server based application.

Comment: No, you can only do HTML elements on the client, plus JavaScript. If you could find a plugin that will display a stream rendered on the server, that could work. The big question, though, is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you're going to need to use JavaScript since the API for canvas is written in it.

Another issue you're having, I think is you data layering. Which will eventually look like this:

`C# Server <- Javascript Events -> Canvas View`

Basically Javascript will call async methods to your server every so often, either getting data (current high scores) or sending data (giving new scores). In turn it will update the canvas view. Also, everything that happens to the canvas will be handled in JavaScript through its event handling system. These event handles can trigger other events like calls to the server or a local event like the current falling block to rotate.

I don't see away around JavaScript being a huge part of this, since you can't really do a real time game without a lot of it being client side, at least in a web based game.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there an easy way to protect your scripts to prevent the user from cheating (for a regular user with no developing knowledge)?

Comment: Look into obfuscation. It's pretty great and can help you save space. Simple google search showed jscompress, try that.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answered it this answer satisfies.

Comment: You can't prevent the user from messing with the script, ultimately. But you can enforce game rules on the server and if the client tries to cheat by doing something against the rules, you can have the server respond appropriately. That is, don't let the client keep track of anything critical that isn't also tracked by the server.